# Sqldf error in R when join two databases

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm trying to do a simple left join using the sqldf (as I usually do):

```
tot3<-sqldf("select a.*, b.* 
from tot2 a 
left join lagd b on a.rowid = b.rowid+1")
```

but this time I received a message:

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : too many SQL variables
```

Does anybody know how can I overcome it?

Comment: What are the columns in the `tot2` and `lagd` data frames?  Can you include this information in your question?

Comment: Probable duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586868/error-in-r-using-sqldf-too-many-sql-variables

Comment: Actually I think the problem is that there are several columns in each database (tot2 has 1010 and lagd 505). That is because I can't put all the columns here :(

Comment: Also, the column's name are not duplicate. Before the left join I changed the names of the lagd using "paste" function. I also check it again right now and everything's fine.